# Can XProc 3 handle any XPath 3.1 value/type?

Tags: xproc, xpath-3.1

While reading up on XProc 3 I wonder whether a step like an XSLT 3 stylesheet can return any type of the XSLT 3 or XPath 3.1 data model.

The spec in http://spec.xproc.org/master/head/xproc/#documents.9 has a section saying

> If the result is a map, array or any atomic value, a JSON document is
>   created and content-type application/json is used.

I am struggling to understand what would happen with sequences in general, e.g. a sequence of arrays of nodes (e.g. type `array(node())*`) or a sequence of maps from an atomic type to a node (e.g. a type `map(xs:string, node())*`) as that is not a type JSON could handle, at least not in the sense I know JSON or the XSLT 3 serialization spec allows JSON serialization for.

Any insight as to whether XProc 3 is meant to allow passing on any XDM 3.1 sequence between steps?

Answer (score 0):

This is an absolutely valid question and I think some clarification in the spec is due. Would you mind raising an issue on Github?
https://github.com/xproc/3.0-specification/issues/

Gerrit

Comment: Following your request I have raised https://github.com/xproc/3.0-specification/issues/808.